# Overlap ::after and ::before pseudo elements with hosting text element

Tags: javascript, html, css, pseudo-element

UPDATE:

I need to hide `@@` from the text, but keep it in HTML.

---

I have elements within HTML - `<mark>@@Text@@</mark>` and basicaly need to hide `@@` from the begining of the text and from the end. Hiding seems to be easy with pseudo elements, but also need to remove space and yellow background from where pseudo elements are.

```css
mark {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
}

mark::before {
  content: '@@';
  position: absolute;
  color: yellow;
  left: 0;
}

mark::after {
  content: '@@';
  position: absolute;
  color: yellow;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <mark>@@Some Text@@</mark> |
  <mark>@@Some Text@@</mark> |
  <mark>@@Some Text@@</mark>
</body>
</html>
```

Code above brings this result:

[image]

While I need is:

[image]

[**DEMO**](https://jsbin.com/qidonuzaqe/edit?html,css,output)

p.s. you can see in the demo strange behaviour - remove a line from CSS and result will look as in my first image. Types something in HTML and it will again brake. No idea why this happens, but would love to get some insights on this as well, if possible.

Comment: do you want to remove all @@ with javascript?

Comment: Note that they are not removed properly here on Firefox, your pseudo-elements and original text are not at the exact same place, leaving scattered red pixels shown. Also, I doubt you'll be able to do this in CSS. One would wonder why you want to have these `@@` to start with..

Comment: Same as @Kaddath in Chrome for me.

Comment: Sorry,, post is edited. Though, it doesnt run the same. Anyway - i think I described my problem well. And I would like to remove it with CSS if possible. Thanks

Comment: To be frank, I don't think you're going to manage this with CSS if the `mark` elements get their width from their content.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I can use other element than `mark`

Comment: @Kaddath  that comes from backend. Cant do anything with it

Comment: @bigInt - I just meant, if the elements you're targeting get their width from their content. Doesn't matter that it's `mark`, specifically.

Comment: @bigInt - How are you getting this data from the backend? Is it embedded in the HTML, or are you requesting it via ajax?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder oh, ok. Yes, they get width from the content. Maybe a solution with Javascript then...?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder i get as a string and then create `mark` and set innerhtml

Comment: then the issue is with your script even before this.

Comment: just use mark.innerHTML=backEndDataString.replace(/@@/gm,'');

Comment: @nAviD i need to keep it in HTML

Comment: This begins to look like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), why do you need to keep it in HTML if you don't want to display it? Couldn't you use something like a data attribute if you want to do something with original value? Like: `<mark data-raw-value="@@Some Text@@">Some Text</mark>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below solution is a *hack* and should be used with caution (or not used at all ...)

```css
/* 1.8em is approximately the width of @@, adjust it if needed */

mark {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent:-1.8em;  /* Hide the @@ at the left*/
  margin-right:-1.8em; /* Reduce the width of @@ from the right*/
  overflow: hidden; /* Hide the overflow on the left*/
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* Color only the text*/
  background:
    linear-gradient(red,red) left/calc(100% - 1.8em) 100% no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  background-clip:text;
  color: transparent;
}
/* Replace the yellow background */
mark:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:1.8em;
  bottom:0;
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<mark>@@Some Text@@</mark> |
<mark style="font-size:28px;">@@Some more Text@@</mark> |
<mark>@@Text@@</mark>
```

Comment: *"30px is approximately the width of @@, adjust it if needed"* **LOL** "if"? **:-)** Nicely done, though. I thought of a margin solution too but didn't bother to follow it through because it's so fragile. As you said, *"...with caution (or not used at all ...)"* Still, one has to appreciate the effort.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this is more for the sake of learning some tricks than to use it in a real world ;)

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising :) at least as for the temp solution. Though would be also nice to have it based on the user font-size (then also Javscript would be involved probably)

Comment: @bigInt check the update, it can be based on font-size with em unit

Comment: Thanks, this was actually what I asked. Now I know for sure - its not possible :)

Answer (score 3):

In the comments you've said:

> Maybe a solution with Javascript then...?
>
> i get as a string and then create mark and set innerhtm

Originally my solution (under the line below) was to simply remove them on receipt, but you said that you have to keep them in the HTML.

So, you wrap them in an inline element and hide them, e.g.:

```
mark.innerHTML = theString.replace(/</g, "&lt;")
                          .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
                          .replace(/^@@|@@$/g, "<span class=at>$&</span>");
```

(The first two replaces are to mark up `<` and `&` so we can use `innerHTML`. Remove them if the string is *meant* to have HTML markup in it.)

With this CSS:

```
span.at {
    display: none;
}
```

(Note that I'm assuming these `@@` only appear in the actual text, not in attribute values.)

Live Example:

```js
const theString = "@@SOME TEXT@@";

const mark = document.createElement("mark");
mark.innerHTML = theString.replace(/</g, "&lt;")
                          .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
                          .replace(/^@@|@@$/g, "<span class=at>$&</span>");
document.body.appendChild(mark);
```

```css
span.at {
    display: none;
}
```

---

Original solution:

Then by far the best thing is to remove those `@` when you do that:

```
mark.innerHTML = theString.replace(/^@@|@@$/g, "");
```

Example:

```js
const theString = "@@SOME TEXT@@";

const mark = document.createElement("mark");
mark.innerHTML = theString.replace(/^@@|@@$/g, "");
document.body.appendChild(mark);
```

---

Beware that when you set `innerHTML`, the string is read **as HTML**, not as plain text. So if "SOME TEXT" contains characters that are special in HTML but should be treated literally, the result won't be good:

```js
const theString = "@@<SOME TEXT>huh? where did the rest go?@@";

const mark = document.createElement("mark");
mark.innerHTML = theString.replace(/^@@|@@$/g, "");
document.body.appendChild(mark);
```

If that's the case, create a text node explicitly:

```
mark.appendChild(document.createTextNode(theString.replace(/^@@|@@$/g, "")));
```

Example:

```js
const theString = "@@<SOME TEXT>ah, there it is@@";

const mark = document.createElement("mark");
mark.appendChild(document.createTextNode(theString.replace(/^@@|@@$/g, "")));
document.body.appendChild(mark);
```

Comment: @bigInt wrap them in `span` and hide the spans.

Comment: @bigInt - That was important information to put in the question.

Answer (score 0):

try with javascript

```
var str = document.getElementsByClassName('mark');

for(var i =0; i <= str.length; i++){
  var res = str[i].innerText.replace("@@", "");
    str[i].innerText = res.replace('@@','');
}
```